# ShinyApp with dynamic text appearing on any change across a number of UI elements

Tags: r, reactive-programming, observable, shiny

I'm interested in developing a Shiny App that would act in the following manner:

1. Update the chart following any changes to the number of user interface elements. *This done through the [`actionButton`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html) / `isolate` construct*.
2. Display a warning text prompting user to click the **<kbd>Update</kbd>** button. ***Outstanding.***
3. Remove the warning text after the **<kbd>Update</kbd>** button was pressed. ***Outstanding.***

## Example

### Approach

- Drawing from one of the examples available via [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) the following example provides access to two functionalities that modify the histogram.
- Histogram is updated upon the **<kbd>Update</kbd>** button click.
- Upon interaction with the UI the [**`observeEvent`**](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) construct should update the warning message that is then passed to `renderText`.
- If there is no interaction with the UI the `renderText` can return empty string.
- `actionButton` should revert warning message string value to empty `c("")`. *Alternative approach making use from [`insertUI`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) / `renderUI` is acceptable.*

### Code

#### `app.R`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Reactive UI"),
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        # Reactive text should appear upon any change here
                        sliderInput(
                            "bins",
                            "Number of bins:",
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            value = 30
                        ),
                        checkboxInput(
                            inputId = "chckBxLg",
                            label = "Log scale",
                            value = FALSE
                        )
                        ,
                        actionButton("btnUpdate", "Update")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(textOutput("msgTxt"),
                              plotOutput("distPlot"))
                ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    # Create placeholder object for msg
    msgUpdateText <- c("")

    # Insert update message text upon change to UI elements
    observeEvent(eventExpr = {
        input$bins
        input$chckBxLg
    },
    handlerExpr = {
        # This message should only show after interaction with the UI
        isolate(msgUpdateText <<-
                    c("You have clicked something, update the chart"))
    })

    # Render text
    output$msgTxt <- renderText(msgUpdateText)

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        input$btnUpdate
        isolate({
            x    <- faithful[, 2]
            if (input$chckBxLg) {
                x <- log(x)
            }
            bins <-
                seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

            # Also delete the text message
            msgUpdateText <<- c("")
        })

        hist(x,
             breaks = bins,
             col = 'darkgray',
             border = 'white')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Problem

The message:

> *You have clicked something, update the chart*

should only appear ***only*** after user interacts with the UI and ***disappear*** after the **`actionButton`** is pressed, instead the message is visible permanently.

[image: App preview]

---

## Side notes

The offered solution should be extensible across a number of UI, elements. The provided, *not-working,* example attempts to capture change to two UI elements:

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = {
    input$bins      # Element 1
    input$chckBxLg  # Element 2
},
handlerExpr = {
    # This message should only show after interaction with the UI
    isolate(msgUpdateText <<-
                c("You have clicked something, update the chart"))
})
```

I'm striving for the code to accommodate a vast number of elements, on the lines

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = {
    input$bins      # Element 1
    input$chckBxLg  # Element 2
    input$title     # Element 3
    input$n         # Element n
    ...             ...
},
handlerExpr = {
    # User interacted with any of the UI elements listed above
    # Update text message to be displayed in the app
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've managed to achieve the desired result. I've brought the necessarily logic into 3 `observeEvent` calls. The first observes any of the inputs changing and sets a variable to `TRUE`. The second observes the updatebutton and sets the variable to `FALSE`. The third observe both the inputs and the updatebutton and renders the warning message based on the variable (if it's `TRUE` it prints, otherwise it's empty).

The only problem I've found is that at the moment it starts off showing the warning message, but I haven't been able to figure out why.

The final code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Reactive UI"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # Reactive text should appear upon any change here
                    sliderInput(
                      "bins",
                      "Number of bins:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = 50,
                      value = 30
                    ),
                    checkboxInput(
                      inputId = "chckBxLg",
                      label = "Log scale",
                      value = FALSE
                    )
                    ,
                    actionButton("btnUpdate", "Update")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(uiOutput("msgui"),
                            plotOutput("distPlot"))
                ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Initialize the value to check if a change happened
  Changebool <<- FALSE

  observeEvent(eventExpr = { #When an input is changed
    input$bins
    input$chckBxLg
  },
  handlerExpr = {  # Change the changebool to TRUE
    Changebool <<- TRUE
  }
  )

  observeEvent(eventExpr = { #When the update button is pressed
    input$btnUpdate
  },
  handlerExpr = {  # Change the changebool to FALSE
    Changebool <<- FALSE
  }
  )

  observeEvent({input$btnUpdate # If any of the inputs change or the update button is pressed
    input$bins
    input$chckBxLg},
               {  # Recreate the message-ui
                 output$msgui <- renderUI({
                   if (Changebool) {  # if a change has happened since last update
                     textOutput("msgTxt")  #Output text
                   } else {  #otherwise
                       #Output nothing
                   } 
                 })
               })

  # Render text
  output$msgTxt <- renderText("You have clicked something, update the chart")

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    input$btnUpdate
    isolate({
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      if (input$chckBxLg) {
        x <- log(x)
      }
      bins <-
        seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    })

    hist(x,
         breaks = bins,
         col = 'darkgray',
         border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I must admit I was fiddling back and forth with this for quite a bit so if you notice anything weird in the code feel free to drop a comment

Comment: Hi, it looks like it could work. It looks like a similar approach to workaround for the `actionButton` reset discussed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/167).